# Windows 10 update the latest breaks ADO connection to Excel files

Tags: excel, windows, ado, dao

The following code works on Windows for many years until windows latest update 
Windows version 1607, OS Build 14393.1770 or later ones.

```
Dim adoSourceCN   As  ADODB.Connection

Set adoSourceCN = New ADODB.Connection

adoSourceCN.CursorLocation = adUseClient
adoSourceCN.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
adoSourceCN.ConnectionString = "C:\test.xls"; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"""
adoSourceCN.open

If (adoSourceCN.State = adStateOpen) Then
    ' Do something ...
End If
```

Generates this error:

> Number: -2147467259
>   Description: Unexpected error from external database driver (1).`

And the similar error happens with `DAO360`.

Did anybody encountered this issue, or similar, and knows how to get around this ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/